# Enable moving to next line on enter click in cell phone for a web site

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a website with many form fields. As it happens, when on desktop, one can move over all fields by clicking TAB button. But when the site is opened up on a small size phone, user has to scroll and touch every time to reach next field. I want to enable movement to the next editable field on clicking ENTER on keypad of the phone. Is there any shortcut to achieve that other than writing a function and add it to every form field ?

I have added the code piece i have implemented

```
handleKeyPress(value, event){
    if(event.key === 'Enter'){
      this.refs[event].focus();
    }
  }

    <input
      onKeyPress={(event) => this.handleKeyPress('email', event)}
      ref = 'name'
    />

    <input
      onKeyPress={(event) => this.handleKeyPress('zip_code', event)}
      ref = 'email'
    />

    <input
      ref = 'zip_code'
    />
```

Comment: show a sample code of what you've tried to shift the control focus

Comment: Usually the keyboards on Android already have a Next key that switches form fields, it appears as a Tab key, but it doesn't output a real Tab. On the IPhone the keyboard has two arrows to navigate form fields.

Comment: @DonnieNosayaba added the code. Is there anything short and sleek that can be done as the project Iam doing changes in is huge and this change might add to loading time.